# In deque we can insert and delete at both ends. Does it violate the queue property?

Tags: queue, deque

Queue is a data structure in which we insert elements from one end (front), and delete elements from the other end (rear). But with a deque we can insert and delete from both ends, so does that violate the property of queue?

Comment: Put it this way; a spork can be used as a spoon, and it can also be used as a fork. Being usable as a spoon doesn't "violate the fork property" because no sensible definition of a fork requires forks to not also be usable as spoons.

Answer (score 1):

A *queue* isn't a property.  It is an abstract data class with the operations, *push_right()* and *pop_left()*.

Likewise, a *deque* is an abstract data class that with the operations, *push_left()*, *push_right()*, *pop_left()*, and *pop_right()*.

This shows the deque operations are a superset of queue operations.

Accordingly, a queue can be implemented with a deque.  IIRC, that is what C++ does.

Since a queue can be implemented with a deque, it doesn't really make sense to say that a deque violates queue properties.  It is more accurate to say that a deque offers extra capabilities.

Hope this helps clarify the situation :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, deque does not violet the queue property.

As per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue):

> In computer science, a double-ended queue (abbreviated to deque) is an abstract data type that **generalizes** a queue, for which elements can be added to or removed from either the front (head) or back (tail)

So it's clear that deque is a generalisation of queue not the violation.

Comment: Thanks for Answering.                                                                                                                                       But if i insert elements from one end(rear) and also deleting elements from same end(rear) then what is the difference between STACK and Dqueue.

Comment: @Abhishek kumar can you do insert and delete in stack other than Top of it? No you cannot. If one way of functionality matches with other this does not mean that both data structures are same.